# Decryption with Node.js crypto module does not result in the encrypted text

Tags: node.js, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

I am using **AES-256-CFB** encryption method to encrypt text but when decrypting using the same parameters it doesn't give the text I encrypted

Code used to encrypt

```
const ss = Buffer.from(decipher.update(sender.ss, "hex", "hex"), "hex");
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(process.env.encryptionMethod, ss, iv);
const encryptedMsg = cipher.update(req.body.msg, "utf8", "utf8") + cipher.final("utf8");
```

Code to Decrypt

```
const decipherMsg = crypto.createDecipheriv(process.env.encryptionMethod, ss, Buffer.from(msg.iv, "hex"));
const msgText = decipherMsg.update(msg.msg.toString("utf8"), "utf8", "utf8") + decipherMsg.final("utf8");
```

I have made sure that the key (ss) and initial vector (iv) are same in both cases. The following is an example:

- req.body.msg: hi
- encryptedMsg: �D
- Buffer of encryptedMsg: <Buffer ef bf bd 44>

---

- msg.msg: <Buffer ef bf bd 44>
- msg.msg.toString("utf8"): �D
- msgText: >�b�

Comment: What is `decipher.update` doing in there? Have you mapped how you're doing encoding / decoding? UTF-8 and HEX seem to be strewn in rather randomly...

Comment: The problem starts (at the latest) with the encryption, where UTF-8 is specified as output encoding, which corrupts the ciphertext. Generate the ciphertext as `Buffer` or use a binary-to-text encoding such as Base64 or hex.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes, I have mapped it out. The reason the input encoding for the message is UTF8 is to support more characters from user input. The rest are sort of arbitrary. As far as I understand, `decipher.update()` is what accepts the data to be encrypted/ decrypted

Comment: @Topaco I tried changing the output encoding for cipher and the input for decipher to hex, but the problem remains.

Comment: @Topaco Nevermind, changing it to hex works. I must have made some mistake before. I'm confused, though. Why does using utf8 corrupt the ciphertext?

Comment: A UTF-8 encoding consists of specific byte sequences, while ciphertexts can in principle contain all possible byte sequences. When UTF-8 decoding the ciphertext, the non-UTF-8 compliant byte sequences are replaced by the byte sequence of the replacement character, which causes the original byte sequences to be lost, irreversibly corrupting the ciphertext. You can find many posts about this on SO.

Comment: See online this sample code https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/W3c